# Conditional statement outputting the wrong command

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

Beginner here so I'm sorry if I made nooby mistakes
I assign di to be the array myworld[] depending the the user input it'll assign the di into the appropriate array position, but for some reason the if statement keep outputting "make" instead of "change" when my input is 'c'

I tried to remove else if and put if for all of them, or got rid of else if and just use else.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {

char di;
char myword[] = {'d','m','s' ,'c'};
do {
    cout << "Make a selection:" << endl;
    cout << "d - insert 1$ bill" << endl; 
    cout << "m - view menu" << endl; 
    cout << "s - select an item" << endl; 
    cout << "c - get change" << endl; 
    cin >> di;
    if (di == 'd')
        di = myword[0];
    else if (di == 'c')
        di = myword[3]; 
}while (!myword);

if (myword[0])
    cout << "make";
else if (myword[3])
    cout << "change";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What will `myword[0]` evaluate to? Will `!myword` ever be true? What you want here is probably a `switch` statement.

Comment: Firstly, correct your indenting because it's a little confusing to look at. What are you trying to achieve with that do while loop. Do you want multiple inputs? If so, you need a type to actually hold those values. You can look into c++ container types such as vector. For instance. `std::vector<char> vec; vec.push_back( di );` Then check all the inputs stored inside `vec`

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forgot to make a comparison inside if statement. For now you are just saying `if('d'!= 0)` which is always true. Perhaps you tried to make `if(di == myword[0])`. The same applies for the `else if` statement.